# Getting error while creating build variant source set in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build, android-build-flavors, android-build-type

I'm new to Android Studio build variant. I created a new app, edited the build flavors in gradle and successfully synced it. But when I add source set for one of the build variant(demoDebug) it shows error.

**Module level build.gradle file:**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.shaon.myappbuildtest"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

            debug {
                applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
                debuggable true
            }
        }

        flavorDimensions "version"
        productFlavors {
            demo {
                dimension "version"
                applicationIdSuffix ".demo"
                versionNameSuffix "-demo"
            }
            full {
                dimension "version"
                applicationIdSuffix ".full"
                versionNameSuffix "-full"
            }
        }
        sourceSets { debug { java.srcDirs = ['src/debug/java', 'src/debug/java/'] } }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
```

**Project Structure Screen Shot:**

[image: project structure]

**Manifest.xml for main**

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.shaon.myappbuildtest">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**Manifest.xml for demoDebug**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.shaon.myappbuildtest.demo.debug">

        <application>
            <activity android:name="com.example.shaon.myappbuildtest.demo.debug.MainActivityDemoDebug"></activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

**Error that I am getting when creating the folder for source set for demoDebug:**

```
Manifest merger failed : Overlay manifest:package attribute declared at AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-58 value=(com.example.shaon.myappbuildtest.demo.debug)
has a different value=(com.example.shaon.myappbuildtest.demo.debug) declared in main manifest at AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-47
Suggestion: remove the overlay declaration at AndroidManifest.xml   and place it in the build.gradle:
    flavorName {
        applicationId = "com.example.shaon.myappbuildtest.demo.debug"
    }
```

What did I do wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `package` parameter from `AndroidManifest.xml`. Gradle plugin will automatically fill it for you using declaration from `build.gradle`.

Comment: @RashedulHasan [Explanation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge) why merge operation performed. And [behavior](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) of build tools concerning `applicationId` and `package`.

Comment: Thanks it works now. But a little bit of explanation would be great. In my main Manifest `package="com.example.shaon.myappbuildtest"` and in demoDebug Manifest I didn't include any package but the Merged Manifest is showing `package = com.example.shaon.myappbuildtest.demo.debug`

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot.